# How to remove a specific keyword from a given user input?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, strtok

I'm working on a program that takes user input two times. The user will input a sentence, and then enter a key phrase to remove each found match throughout the sentence, and return what's left. The code I have below for the 'logic' is...

```
 char delim[AFFIX];
 strcpy(delim, userInput);                   //storing the phrase user wants to remove
 char *token = strtok(sentence, delim);     
    while (token)
    {
        cout << token << endl;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
```

The issue I'm having is that strtok removes every single instance of a character found. For example, if the user wishes to remove all instances of 'pre' then the word "preformed" would turn into "fo m d" instead of formed. Is there a way to restrict strtok from removing EVERY instance of a character found, and only remove the series of characters?

I understand that working with strings or vectors would make my life much easier, but I want to work with arrays of chars. I'm really sorry if this isn't clear enough, I'm very new to c++. Any advice on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `strtok()` is designed to work that way. I would suggest using `strtok()` with the first character of the delimiter only (in this case `p`). Then with each character found, compare the original string from that point to the delimiter string.

Comment: You could use [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr) to find the next occurrence of `delim` in `sentence`. But yes, `std::string` would make your life so much easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

A easy and more or less dirty solution would be to just add spaces before and after your search word. To ensure it's actually a full word and not part of a word.

**Eg:**

- Input: "pre"
- Check: " pre "

To ensure you also cut the first word you would need to check the first part of the string and add a space before it if the first word is also the inputted word.

**Example:**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void removeSubstrs(std::string& s, std::string& p) { 
  std::string::size_type n = p.length();
  for (std::string::size_type i = s.find(p);
      i != std::string::npos;
      i = s.find(p))
      s.erase(i, n);
}

void check(std::string& s, std::string& p) {
   int slen = s.length();
   int plen = p.length();
   std::string firstpart = s.substr (0,plen);
   std::string lastpart = s.substr (slen-plen,slen);
   if (firstpart == p) {
       s = " " + s;
   }
   if (lastpart == p) {
       s += " ";
   }
}

int main ()
{
  std::string str = "pre test inppre test pre";
  std::string search = "pre";
  std::string pattern = " " + search + " ";
  
  check(str, search);
  removeSubstrs(str, pattern);
  std::cout << str << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

strtok isn't the right choice here, you can think of strtok's 2nd argument as a list of delimiters (each char in that list is a delimiter) and it breaks the string into tokens using those delimiters.
A better solution would be something along the lines of strstr and strcat.
maybe something like this (using MSVC++)

```
void removeSubstr(char *string, const char *sub, int n) {
    char *match;
    int len = strlen(sub);
    while ((match = strstr(string, sub))) {
        *match = '\0';
        strcat_s(string, n, match + len);
    }
}

int main() {
    char test[] = "abcxyz123xyz";
    removeSubstr(test, "xyz", sizeof(test) / sizeof(char));
    cout << test << endl;
}
```

strcat_s is a more secure version of strcat (MSVC++ likes it way more than strcat :p)
There are better ways of doing this ofc but I'm restricting myself to char arrays here as you requested...